I want to rotate the scoreboard 360 degree and putting it on loop, but it detached when I try to rotate it
Video reference:
The result I want to achieve:
The scoreboard's elements are all snitched together with random stuff and join together, but I can't seem to find a way to join them properly. When I try to rotate them, the elements are significantly detached.

Yo're going to have to give us a clue about the 'random stuff', or we can't help. Maybe the best way would be to strip the scoreboard out of your scene, with its animation, and share on https://blend-exchange.com/, following the instructions there, and pasting the provided link into your post.

I think you have an issue with some parent-child relationships, possibly. Not sure. That or one of them has a child of constraint or something like that.
I like to work like this as much as possible, especially with static objects like props and architecture. It allows me to keep all the objects clean and procedural, while still being able to "join" them and then apply more modifiers to all the objects at once.

I think this will help your problem with joining the objects. Separate your elements into logical sections like, Scoreboard, letters, etc. and then instance each section. Then just parent those instanced objects to your scoreboard or another parent object that they will all follow.
That or you can just put all of the sign elements into one collection and instance that. Then it will work essentially like a joined object, but you can still refer to the base collection and have all the objects separate and easy to work with.
